# Change Url in WebSphere

Tags: url, websphere, friendly-url, websphere-portal

So the company I work for has a website in WebSphere, and all the url´s pages are too long and because of it are considerer trash by google. An example:

https://www.victoria-seguros.pt/wps/portal/institucional/victoria/institucional/victorianosmedia

How can I change the url to something like this:

https://www.victoria-seguros.pt/victorianosmedia

Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Please share instruction for content you want to change
If you want to change url of Application for App, Please edit it in:

```
Enterprise Applications View more information about this page   Expand or collapse

Enterprise Applications > WebCSR > Context Root For Web Modules
Context Root For Web Modules

Configure values for context roots in web modules.
Web module                      URI                           Context Root
WebCSR      VTBWebCSR-Rel_10.0_maint.dev.war,WEB-INF/web.xml    /WebCSR
```

Context Root is url if you change to update link connect wit url for context

Thanks and regards

tandn